# Comparative Sentences (比较句：A没有B) - Is the grammar of the following combined sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

### This question is about Comparative Sentences (比较句：`A没有B`)

So we have the following two sentences:

- 爸爸的手机2000 块。
- 哥哥的手机6000 块。

The assignment is to make these into one sentence using the `A没有B` structure and the character `贵`.

Is the following answer correct? Or is there something wrong with this sentence please:

爸爸的手机`没有`哥哥`贵`。

Or should you repeat 的 at least? ->

爸爸的手机`没有`哥哥的`贵`。

Or should you always repeat the structure from the first half completely? ->

爸爸的手机`没有`哥哥的手机`贵`。

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison is between [the father's **cell phone**] and [the brother's **cell phone**]

爸爸的**手机**没有**哥哥**贵 would mean "my father's **cell phone** is not as expensive as my **brother**"

Either "爸爸的**手机**没有哥哥的**手机**贵" or "爸爸的**手机**没有哥哥**的**贵" would be correct